# How can you attach an Issue Number to SVN commits via command line?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have set up my repository in TortoiseSVN to enable the bugtraq properties which enables the Issue Number field in the commit dialog.

I am wondering how to pass the issue number to SVN when issuing a command line "svn commit" command, as we have some developers who work in unix and don't use TortoiseSVN.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseSVN's [bugtraq features](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html) are rather one way. It provides a means of extracting Bug IDs from commit messages so that they can be displayed in a useful way in the client. You need to define a regular expression for how you refer to bugs (eg for 'BUG1234' or '#1234'), and then you have to ensure that everyone in the team uses that shorthand consistently in their log messages, for instance:

```
"BUG1234: fixed up the Foo handler"
```

Once you have this set up then it means that in the TortoiseSVN log viewer will detect the bug IDs and show them in a separate column. If you have the URL fields set up too then it'll produce a hyperlink that will open up the bug tracker at this ID.

What it doesn't do though is give integration changes to the bug tracker. So if you close a bug then SVN doesn't know anything about it.

So for the users on the command line, if they use consistent notation for bug IDs in their commit messages then everything will appear correctly for the TortoiseSVN users. However, the command line users won't get any benefit from them as there's only a few GUI clients that use the bugtraq fields. (In any case, a hyperlink in a log message isn't very useful in a command line client).